# Case-insensitive matching with Eshell?

Tags: emacs, pattern-matching, elisp, glob, eshell

How can you do case-insensitive pattern matching with Eshell? With Zsh, one can use "globbing tags" (i.e., if the extended_glob is turned on) such as in

```
print L(#i)in(#I)ux
```

which would match `LINux` for instance.

Is there anything like that for Eshell? From what I know Eshell doesn't have a support for something like Zsh's "globbing tags", but do you know if there is an Eshell predicate for case-insensitive matching? If there isn't, do you have any suggestion of how to define a predicate in Eshell to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the variable `eshell-glob-case-insensitive` to true to enable case-insensitive globbing in eshell.

Comment: Thanks! I've missed this variable. Just a sidenote. With Zsh, if you put the `(#i)` flag at the beginning of the path like `(#i)/Doc/` Zsh will search for `DOC`, `DoC`, etc. But because you can also use the flag in the middle of your search pattern, Zsh allows you to decrease the number of matches the shell will look for -- which may speed up the matching process. For this reason, I think it would be nice if eshell would have something like Zsh flags. But maybe I'm just complaining too much :)

Answer (score 10):

`(setq eshell-glob-case-insensitive t)` **Does not work.**

`(setq eshell-cmpl-ignore-case t)` **This works.** Put it in your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`.

Comment: May I ask, what is the purpose of (setq eshell-glob-case-insensitive t) in emacs?